# Waterline fails to honor model type

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm having an issue where my model is defined with an attribute of type `boolean` but at some point it's being interpreted as a string.

For example, with a model that looks like this:

```
{
  attributes: {
    id: 'string'
    boolean_thing: {type: 'boolean', columnName: 'BooleanThing'},
  }
}
```

when given a request like this:

```
/api/foo?boolean_thing=false
```

will result in the `where` criteria being passed to the adapter looks like this:

```
{ 
  where: { 
    BooleanThing: 'false' 
  },
  limit: 30,
  skip: 0 
}
```

I'm currently running sails@0.10.0-rc8. Does anyone know if this is a bug or a misconfiguration issue on my part?

Comment: is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this problem: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1818?

You can do this as a fix:

```
var bol = (req.params("boolean_thing") == "true");
mymodel.find().where({BooleanThing: bol}).exec(...
```